# Using numpy broadcasting to compute the partial sum of a series

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have to compute the following sum, `S` defined as:

[image: Sum of 5 terms]

I have tried the following as a function:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.4,2.6,3, 1.2, 3.4])
b = np.array([-5,7,2,1.1,1.8])
c = np.array([3.3,30,15,0.4,28])
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 600)
def S(t):
  return np.sum([a[i]*np.cos(b[i]*t + c[i]) for i in range(5)], axis=0)
```

This works just fine. But I wonder if there is pure numpy version that uses broadcasting without relying on Python's list comprehension?

I have tried:

```
def S(t):
  return np.sum(a*np.cos(b*t + c), axis=0)
```

When I compue `S(t)` I get the following error:

```
...
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (600,)
```

How can I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer by adding a newaxis to `a`, `b`, and `c` arrays as follows:

```
def S(t):
   return np.sum(a[:,None]*cos(b[:,None]*t + c[:,None]), axis=0)
```

or

```
def S(t):
   return np.sum(a[:,np.newaxis]*cos(b[:,np.newaxis]*t + c[:,np.newaxis]), axis=0)
```

**Edit**:

As suggested by Michael in the comment, a better solution, would be to add a newaxis to `t` instead (note that in this case the sum is carried out over `axis=1`):

```
def S(t):
   return np.sum(a*cos(b*t[:,None] + c), axis=1)
```

Comment: You could reshape *t* `np.sum(a*np.cos(b*t[:,None]+c))`, too.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny: Thank you! I've updated it.

Comment: I am guessing that OP wants `np.sum(a[:,None] * np.cos(b[:,None]*t[None,:] + c[:,None]), 0)` (not summing over `t`).

Answer (score 1):

### How to do it?

For broadcasting you need ones in dimensions you want to have "copied" values. So it works like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.4,2.6,3, 1.2, 3.4])
b = np.array([-5,7,2,1.1,1.8])
c = np.array([3.3,30,15,0.4,28])
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 600).reshape(-1,1)

np.sum(a*np.cos(b*t+c), axis=1)
```

### How to check if you did the right thing?

One neat hack you can do is to put `sympy.symbols` into your arrays and do the same thing. Then you obtain formulas for what it calculated for you:

```
import sympy

a = np.array(sympy.symbols([f"a{i}" for i in range(5)]))
b = np.array(sympy.symbols([f"b{i}" for i in range(5)]))
c = np.array(sympy.symbols([f"c{i}" for i in range(5)]))
t = np.array(sympy.symbols([f"t{i}" for i in range(10)])).reshape(-1,1)

cos = np.vectorize(sympy.cos)
np.sum(a*cos(b*t+c), axis=1)
```

this gives you

```
array([a0*cos(b0*t0 + c0) + a1*cos(b1*t0 + c1) + a2*cos(b2*t0 + c2) + a3*cos(b3*t0 + c3) + a4*cos(b4*t0 + c4),
       a0*cos(b0*t1 + c0) + a1*cos(b1*t1 + c1) + a2*cos(b2*t1 + c2) + a3*cos(b3*t1 + c3) + a4*cos(b4*t1 + c4),
       a0*cos(b0*t2 + c0) + a1*cos(b1*t2 + c1) + a2*cos(b2*t2 + c2) + a3*cos(b3*t2 + c3) + a4*cos(b4*t2 + c4),
       a0*cos(b0*t3 + c0) + a1*cos(b1*t3 + c1) + a2*cos(b2*t3 + c2) + a3*cos(b3*t3 + c3) + a4*cos(b4*t3 + c4),
       a0*cos(b0*t4 + c0) + a1*cos(b1*t4 + c1) + a2*cos(b2*t4 + c2) + a3*cos(b3*t4 + c3) + a4*cos(b4*t4 + c4),
       a0*cos(b0*t5 + c0) + a1*cos(b1*t5 + c1) + a2*cos(b2*t5 + c2) + a3*cos(b3*t5 + c3) + a4*cos(b4*t5 + c4),
       a0*cos(b0*t6 + c0) + a1*cos(b1*t6 + c1) + a2*cos(b2*t6 + c2) + a3*cos(b3*t6 + c3) + a4*cos(b4*t6 + c4),
       a0*cos(b0*t7 + c0) + a1*cos(b1*t7 + c1) + a2*cos(b2*t7 + c2) + a3*cos(b3*t7 + c3) + a4*cos(b4*t7 + c4),
       a0*cos(b0*t8 + c0) + a1*cos(b1*t8 + c1) + a2*cos(b2*t8 + c2) + a3*cos(b3*t8 + c3) + a4*cos(b4*t8 + c4),
       a0*cos(b0*t9 + c0) + a1*cos(b1*t9 + c1) + a2*cos(b2*t9 + c2) + a3*cos(b3*t9 + c3) + a4*cos(b4*t9 + c4)],
      dtype=object)
```

Notice that this couldn't work with numpy's cosine since that only works for floats. But

```
cos = np.vectorize(sympy.cos)
```

gives you a version of sympys cosine that works on arrays elementwise.